# Change Kendo Chart tooltip text color using CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

All of my chart's tooltip's text colors are black, which doesn't work well with my chart colors. I've been trying to change the color to white using CSS, but somehow it doesn't change.

I'm looking for a solution which applies a color to **all charts** on my screen.

Inspecting the element source of one of the tooltips, shows me this:

```
<div class="k-tooltip k-chart-tooltip" style="font: 12px/normal Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0); border-image: none; left: 497px; top: 368px; position: absolute; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; opacity: 1; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">70.25%</div>
```

I've tried a few things, like:

```
.k-chart .k-tooltip {
    color: white !important;
}
.k-tooltip.k-chart-tooltip {
    color: white !important;
}
.k-chart-tooltip {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: You can set color in jQuery, see example http://jsfiddle.net/nmcLh0x1/1/. If you are using MVC wrapper for kendo-chart then also tooltip options are available.

Comment: I need something which I can set once, after which it applies to all charts on my page, so I don't want to set the same tooltip options for each chart. I suppose a JQuery script would work though, but I can't access JSFiddle.net from here at work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CSS, set this class for styling

```
.k-tooltip,.k-chart-tooltip
{
     color: white;
}
```

Or

Using jQuery, you can set kendo chart tooltip color, same you can do with mvc wrapper
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmcLh0x1/1/)

```js
        function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Title"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                chartArea: {
                    background: ""
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "line",
                    style: "smooth"
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Series1",
                    color: "red",
                    data: [50, 100]
                },{
                    name: "Series2",
                    color: "blue",
                    data: [null, 100, 150]
                }],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: "{0:c}"
                    },
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    axisCrossingValue: -10
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: [2002, 2003, 2004],
                    majorGridLines: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,  
                    font: "0.8em Segoe UI",
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #",
                    color: "white"
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.common.min.css"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.default.min.css"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for a jQuery script (or CSS) which updates the tooltip color of all charts on the page. I'd rather not set the color manually for each chart, since I've got too many of them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Title"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                chartArea: {
                    background: ""
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "line",
                    style: "smooth"
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Series1",
                    color: "red",
                    data: [50, 100]
                },{
                    name: "Series2",
                    color: "blue",
                    data: [null, 100, 150]
                }],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: "{0:c}"
                    },
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    axisCrossingValue: -10
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: [2002, 2003, 2004],
                    majorGridLines: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,  
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #",
                   
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
```

```css
.k-tooltip,.k-chart-tooltip
{
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.common.min.css"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.default.min.css"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```